# Is it possible to use php files in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I'm looking captcha security code but most of them using with php so is it possible using php file in MVC3 ?

Comment: you cannot just plop PHP code through MVC razor code if that's what you mean...

Comment: Try this, good luck :) http://mvc3captcha.codeplex.com/

Comment: pls think before posting what you are saying

Comment: pls think before adding comment why you can't understand how other user can understand and answer my post @user1006544

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is possible to use PHP *alongside* MVC (keeping them completely independent and having them communicate solely through HTTP), but that would present gigantic practical problems for all but the most trivial of cases.